# How to download Release Candidates FeatureFreeze versions?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04

There are https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze

They are listed in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule

Theres is no links to correct one.

How to download now 19

February 27th

Warning /!\ FeatureFreeze, Warning /!\ Debian Import Freeze

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ Cant understand since different dates shows folders and dont have 20.20 folder.

Comment: I've written an answer below; using links that will always work.  Feature freeze has been reached, ML reminder sent etc. We aren't at RC candidates yet; it's still only DAILY images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/

Images are currently daily, so click on the FOCAL DAILY for a 20.04 image.  Currently that will take you to http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds where you can select your flavor or image.

Note I've not gone further than that; as if I do the images available today will be gone tomorrow with a new 'daily' and as a result the build number changes.

When you've navigated to to the image you want where you can enter your QA (Quality Assurance) test session details, any bugs etc, you'll find a DOWNLOAD link (*Link to the download information*) at the top.

FYI: I'll also provide my 'download' script for grabbing the Lubuntu daily..

```
#!/bin/sh
rm *.old
mv focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync.old
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
zsync -u http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/focal-desktop-amd64.iso  focal-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
```

Early in the cycle the 'daily' is produced weekly, later in the cycle it maybe produced twice a day (DAILY really means interval, it's most commonly once per day).

Comment: The Ubuntu 20.04 DAILY image will remain 408 which is why I didn't navigate to lower down. eg. today's daily is http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds/208255/testcases for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64, but that link/build won't allow download when the next build is created, it won't allow new QA info to be added etc was a new build (next 'daily' image) finished building.

Comment: FYI:  The reason I provided my Lubuntu script was the use of *current* in the URL instead of the *build* number, it allows the same script to be run each day, where as the link I mention in the iso.qa.ubuntu.com web sites provide only the current build.  Lubuntu was used as it was already on my screen so I could copy/paste with no effort.